# Iterating over a container of unique_ptr's

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, unique-ptr

How does one access unique_ptr elements of a container (via an iterator) without taking ownership away from the container? When one gets an iterator to an element in the container is the element ownership still with the container? How about when one dereferences the iterator to gain access to the unique_ptr? Does that perform an implicit move of the unique_ptr?

I find I'm using shared_ptr a lot when I need to store elements in a container (not by value), even if the container conceptually owns the elements and other code simply wishes to manipulate elements in the container, because I'm afraid of not being able to actually access the unique_ptr elements in the container without ownership being taken from it.

Any insights?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As long as you don't try to make a copy of the `unique_ptr`, you can just use it.  You'll have to "double dereference" the iterator to get to the pointer's value, just as you would have to with `shared_ptr`.  Here's a brief example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <class C>
void
display(const C& c)
{
    std::cout << '{';
    if (!c.empty())
        std::cout << *c.front();
    for (auto i = std::next(c.begin()); i != c.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << ", " << **i;
    std::cout << "}\n";
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::unique_ptr<int> Ptr;
    std::vector<Ptr> v;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
        v.push_back(Ptr(new int(i)));
    display(v);
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        **i += 2;
    display(v);
}
```

If you do (accidentally) make a copy of the `unique_ptr`:

```
Ptr p = v[0];
```

then you'll find out at compile time.  It won't cause a run time error.  Your use case is why `container<unique_ptr<T>>` was built.  Things should just work, and if they don't, the problem appears at compile time instead of run time.  So code away, and if you don't understand the compile time error, then ask another question back here.

Comment: Okay I think that clarifies things for me. I've been in the habit of using the new for_each function with a lambda whose parameter is the element passed by value, NOT by reference, but I guess I'll have to make it reference for unique_ptr elements if I want to avoid an attempted copy / move.  P.S. if I dereference the iterator once, and take a reference to that result, I assume this avoids an attempted copy? I mean like:  
`for(Container::iterator it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++)  
{  
    unique_ptr<blah>& element = &*it; // No attempted copy?  
}`  

Thanks Howard, btw.

Comment: Yes, I think that should work fine.  Though you've got an extra `&` in your code.  But the compiler will tell you where.

Comment: You should be able to dereference it to a:   blah& element = **it;   still without a copy, I think. (Probably more useful.)

Answer (score 72):

With `auto` and the range-based for-loops of C++11 this becomes relatively elegant:

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr< YourClass >> pointers;
for( auto&& pointer : pointers ) {
    pointer->functionOfYourClass();
}
```

The reference `&` to the `std::unique_ptr` avoids the copying and you can use the `uniqe_ptr` without dereferencing.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a difference between using `auto &` and `auto &&` in this case? This reference suggests the double & http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for , both seem to compile

Comment: Good question. I found [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) (see Explanation/1) which suggests that `auto&&` may work as lvalue and rvalue depending on the initializer. I adapt the example accordingly.

Comment: Could it be that `const auto &` works best?

Comment: @JanHošek: That obviously depends an what you want to do. In the question it is nowhere stated that the object is not modified by the function. If you can, use const.